# Param is missing or the value is empty: within new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into this issue working with a form in rails, and was wondering if anybody could take a quick look with it.

My view looks like

```
= form_for @form_submission do |f|
 - if @form_submission.errors.any?
   #error_explanation
    %h2= "#{pluralize(@form_submission.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this form_submission from being saved:"
    %ul
      - @form_submission.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

..and my controller is like so

```
class FormSubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  invisible_captcha only: [:create], on_spam: :handle_spam

def new
 @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

 if @form_submission.save
  redirect_to thank_you_path
 else
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end

private

 def handle_spam
   redirect_to root_path
 end

 def form_submission_params
   params.require(:form_submission).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :organization, :email, :phone)
 end
end
```

Ultimately my problem is that I don't know what params i'm missing.  Or even if my value is empty, how would I know, and what could I do to resolve that?

Comment: what your `new` action supposed to do here ?  `new` is used mostly to instantiate an object and that is followed by a `create` action which should accept the whitelist params from your strong param to create an object.

Comment: whit new action you just render new form and with create action you will save your data. Also use `pry` gem for debagging apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard rails approach to forms is your new action is a 'GET' and is used to show the new view for the creation of a resource. The form 'POST's to the create action with the form fields added to the params hash. Your controller methods should be

```
def new
  @form_submission = FormSubmission.new
end

def create
  @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

  if @form_submission.save
    redirect_to thank_you_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Check your routes by running rake routes in the terminal and make sure you have a routes to that point to form_submissions#new and form_submissions#create.

When you click on the submit button you will be able to view the parameters that are being passed in the logs and it should look something like

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"someRandomStuff", "form_submission"=>{"first_name"=>"value entered in first_name field", "last_name"=>"value entered in last_name field"}, "commit"=>"Value of submit button"}
```

Are you really creating a resource called FormSubmission?

Comment: Hey thank you so much, all I needed was the second method.

Comment: ...and yes, I know it sounds goofy, but I am creating a resources called From Submission.  (it wasn't my choice)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it the wrong way.

this is what you should do :

```
def new
  @form_submission = FormSubmission.new
end

def create
  @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)
  if @form_submission.save
   redirect_to thank_you_path
  else
   redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

As said in comments,

"new" action is used to initialize your ressource as empty or with default value.

"create" action is used to save your new ressource